# ¿Como configurar bien netbeans y javafx? He intentado casi todo y sigo teniendo estos errores

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, ubuntu, javafx

Necesito usar javafx con Netbeans, pero no logro que funcione, he intentado desde el jdk 8 hasta el 13, desde netbeans 8.2 hasta el 11.1 y siempre me da los mismos errores y ya agote los tutoriales siempre tengo el mismo resultado. Ayuda [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [Ver aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21671967/5587982). Descarga todo del sitio oficial.

Comment: Instala el SDK desde el enlace azul.